# Carousel issue in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

i am trying to make carousel dynamic by fetching the pictures of carousel from database but i am unable to set css classes correctly because of which all the pictures are being shown at once

I tried to use index of the images like if it is the 0th index which means first image then we should make it active otherwise make it just carousel-item
[this is the code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ofQ.png)

```
<div class="carousel-inner" *ngFor="let doc of   banner_arr;let i=index;">
  <h4>{{i}}</h4>
  <div class="{{i}}===0 ? 'carousel-item active' : 'carousel-item' ">
    <img src="{{doc.image_url}}"  alt="{{i}}==0?First slide:{{i}}==1?Second slide:Third slide">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your css code, defining  carousel-item and active style ? Are you using a carousel library, or made it yourself ?

Comment: hey i dont have anything for carousel css because i am using the bootstrap carousel and used its css library

Comment: So indeed, as Eliseo states, you're usage of `{{ }}` is wrong, just have to fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sure the "*ngFor" are in the div with class carousel-item

you can use [ngClass] or [class.active].

Better use "binding" (the ``` [``] ```) instead of interpolation

```
<div class="carousel-item" [class.active]="i===0">
    <img [src]="doc.image_url" 
          [attr.alt]="i==0?First slide:i==1?'Second slide':'Third slide'">
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: I made sometime ago a bootstrap 5 carousel in Angular in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7l36rf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,angular.json), check the angular.json and package.json, be careful because is related to Angular 12, but should work in Angular 15 or 16.

Comment: hey thanks for such fast response but i tried your way it was not working still and can you tell me why my code was not working

Comment: @Aman, What carousel are you using? If it's a bootstrap carousel remember that the *ngFor should be if the div with the class "carousel-item" (else you create several carousel with an unique image instead an unique carousel with several images

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1CUL.png)

just do it like this as answered by Eliseo and declare these two functions in ts file

```
prevSlide() {
  this.activeIndex = (this.activeIndex === 0) ? this.banner_arr.length - 1 : this.activeIndex - 1;
}

nextSlide() {
  this.activeIndex = (this.activeIndex === this.banner_arr.length - 1) ? 0 : this.activeIndex + 1;
}
```